# to assign value to a particular cell of datagridview

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have a `datagridview` view which has quantity and price whose multplied value should be displayed in amount column of the `dgview.` I am pasting the code tried so far.But it throws error in the following line.

```
 dgvpricelist.Rows[i].Cells["totalamount"].Value = totalprice;
```

The error thrown is `"Stack overflow exception error"`.Have no idea why the error is thrown

```
 public void totalcalculation()
    {

        if (dgvpricelist.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            double TAmount = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < dgvpricelist.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(dgvpricelist.Rows[i].Cells["quantity"].Value);
                double itemPrice = Convert.ToDouble(dgvpricelist.Rows[i].Cells["intpricelvl1"].Value);

                totalprice = quantity * itemPrice;
                dgvpricelist.Rows[i].Cells["totalamount"].Value = totalprice;

                edittotalprice = Convert.ToDouble(dgvpricelist.Rows[i].Cells["totalamount"].Value);
                TAmount += edittotalprice;
                //txtboxtaxvalue.Text = tax.ToString();
                //txtboxtotalvalue.Text = total.ToString();
                //TAmount = edittotalprice;
            }

            int roundedtotal = (int)Math.Round(TAmount);
            txtboxstotalvalue.Text = TAmount.ToString();
            txtboxtotalvalue.Text = roundedtotal.ToString();
        }
```

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for your exception.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll